# How do I transform a tidy dataset into an alluvial-friendly format? (ggalluvial)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a problem getting data in a suitable format to make an alluvial diagram with ggalluvial(one row per alluvium). I want to plot the flows between diffrent classes from year 2018 to 2019.

Is this possible with some dplyr magic? :)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)

id <- as.character(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

year <- as.character(c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019))

class <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A")

df <- data.frame(id, year, class)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you do not need to work your data, as:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)
df$class <- as.factor(df$class) # only put this as factor
ggplot(df,aes(x = year, stratum = class, alluvium = id, fill = class, label = class)) +
       scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set2") +
       geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "rightleft",color = "darkgray") +
       geom_stratum() + 
       theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Looks nice! :) But when I tried the same code on my real dataset it didnt work. Got a warning: "Compution failed in 'stat_alluvial()' : Duplicate identifieras for rows (.....

Comment: You're welcome! Seems you have some duplicates rows, but I cannot say without having the data, if you can, you should `dput(your_data)` and post the output, or you can try to create a fake dataframe that creates the error.

Comment: Without data, I cannot help you further. However do you have any output of this `df[duplicated(df),]` ? If so, you have dupes, so you can try do use `library(dplyr)`, with `df <- df %>% distinct()`

Comment: The solution with `dplyr` can delete the duplicates, I tried my example creating `df <- rbind(df,df)`, that creates dupes: the plot does not work, but after the `dplyr` solution, it still work. My advice is to remove the duplicates.